# What are other ways to express "something becomes more and more important"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence

For example, if I would like to use the word "importance", how can I make the sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What comes to mind is "to gain in importance."

> gain: to gradually get (something) or more of (something) as time passes.

[South East Asia is gaining in importance as Japanese investors seek to balance risks...](http://ireport.cnn.com/docs/DOC-912078)

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious phrasing that comes to mind is to say that it is ***of increasing importance***.

Answer (score 0):

Or something gets more importance.